# Request map passed to my anonymous function inside a Compojure handler

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm two days into learning Clojure by writing a simple REST server using [ring-clojure](https://github.com/ring-clojure) and [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) with [ring-json](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json)'s `wrap-json-body` middleware.

#### So far, I have:

A vector `users` containing the users (with a couple of default users):

```
(def users [{:id 0 :username "aname"}
            {:id 1 :username "anothername"}])
```

A function (form?) `save-user` that accepts a map (user) and looks for existing users with the same username. If the username is available, I overwrite the `users` vector to include the new user before returning HTTP 201. If the username is taken, I simply return HTTP 400:

```
(defn save-user [user]
  (prn users)
  (if
    (not-any? #(= (:username %) (:username user)) users)
    (fn [request]
      (def users (conj users user))
      (status
        (response (str "Saved user with username: " (:username user)))
        201))
    (status
      (response (str "User with username '" (:username user) "' already exists"))
      400)))
```

A route for `POST /users` which calls `save-user` with the received map:

```
(defroutes app-routes
       (POST "/users" request (save-user (:body request))))
```

I don't think it matters, but the middleware is applied like this:

```
(def app
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin "*" :access-control-allow-methods "*")
      (wrap-json-response)
      (wrap-keyword-params)
      (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})
      (wrap-defaults (assoc site-defaults :security false))))
```

#### My problem:

For whatever reason, the entire `request` map is passed to the function i pass as `then` inside the `if`. Printing it:

```
  (if
    (not-any? #(= (:username %) (:username user)) users)
    (fn [request]
      (prn request))
    ...
```

... gives me this:

```
{:ssl-client-cert nil, :cookies {}, :remote-addr "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1", :params {}, :flash nil, :route-params {}, :headers {"host" "localhost:3000", "accept" "*/*", "content-length" "42", "content-type" "application/json", "user-agent" "curl/7.43.0"}, :server-port 3000, :content-length 42, :form-params {}, :compojure/route [:post "/users"], :session/key nil, :query-params {}, :content-type "application/json", :character-encoding nil, :uri "/users", :server-name "localhost", :query-string nil, :body {:username "testusername", :password "testpassword"}, :multipart-params {}, :scheme :http, :request-method :post, :session {}}
```

The same happens if I pass an anonymous function as the if's `else`. However, nothing wrong happens when I only pass `(status ...)`, like in the code above.

From what I understand, the `request` map shouldn't be available inside `save-user` at all, since it's not passed as an argument. Why is it passed to my anonymous function, and is there any way to simply ignore it?

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Why are you returning a *function* from the `save-user` function at all? You could just return the response directly (replace `(fn [request]` with `(do`).

Comment: By the way, you should wrap the `users` vector in an [`atom`](http://clojure.org/reference/atoms) and then operate on the atom. Redefining global vars from inside a function is a big no-no in Clojure.

Comment: @glts I'm not returning a function from `save-user`, but I'm passing one to the `if` because I need to _both_ save the user _and_ return the HTTP response object (returned from the `status` function).

As for wrapping the list in an `atom`: thanks! That was because I'm a newbie at this.

Comment: Hi Martin, I’ve converted my comment into an answer. You *are* returning a function from the `if`: in Clojure each conditional branch is an expression that returns a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `save-user` you are returning a *function* that takes a request and returns a response (a handler).

I suppose you should instead just return the response directly. Just replace `(fn [request]` with `(do` to wrap multiple expressions in a single form.

```
(def users (atom [{:id 0 :username "aname"}
                  {:id 1 :username "anothername"}]))

(defn save-user [user]
  (if (not-any? #(= (:username %) (:username user)) @users)
    (do
      (swap! users conj user)
      (status
        (response (str "Saved user with username: " (:username user)))
        201))
    (status
      (response (str "User with username '" (:username user) "' already exists"))
      400)))
```

I’ve also changed the global users var to be an atom. Redefining global vars from inside a function is a big no-no in Clojure.

Comment: You are a champion. `do` was definitely what I was looking for. Thank you so much!